# Any way to do event that fire when any variable in my structure is changed?

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, struct

I have a simple structure, but i don't know to make a event/function call that fires when any variable at this stucture is changed. At C# i can do that easy with get and set, but how i do same at C++?

```
struct Player {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    bool IsAlive;
    float health;
};
```

Sure i can write some custom class, but i want still easy change variables like this

```
Player MyPlayer;
MyPlayer.x = 100;
```

Comment: Write some old school getters/setters?

Comment: Write the getters and setters and add the code to fire the event in the setters

Comment: To keep that syntax, `MyPlayer.x = 100;`, you will have to write custom class `IntEvent`.

Comment: @Jarod42 any example? I am new with C++ don't have any ideas how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is a proxy and overload `operator=`.  Although plain and simple getters and setters might work better.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
private:
    template <typename Type>
    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(Type& in) : data{in} {}
        Proxy& operator=(const Type& object) {
            cout << "Changed data member" << endl;
            this->data = object;
            return *this;
        }
        const Type& operator*() {
            return this->data;
        }

    private:
        Type& data;
    };

public:
    Something(int in) : integer{in} {}
    Proxy<int> integer;
};

int main() {
    auto something = Something{1};

    // trigger code to execute
    something.integer = 2;

    // getting the value will have a different syntax though
    cout << *something.integer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may still have `operator const Type& ()`. BTW, your operator allow modifications without event.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah that would be a better solution.  I just wanted to show OP that this was possible, and minimize the effects on syntax